# Rails: editable/non-editable field depending on user permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms, authorization

I'd like to display a single form in which each user can edit different fields.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
<% if can? :update, item %>  
` <%= f.text_field :title %>
<% else %>
  <%=h f.object.title %>
<% end %>
```

I can package this in a series of helpers (one for each field type) but I also have to check in the controller whether the user can update all submitted fields (in case a malicious user tries to submit fields he is not authorized for).

Is there a cleaner pattern in rails for this type of task? Ideally, I would like to define these access permissions in the model and have the changes propagate to controller and view.

**Edit:**

Using the `readonly` tag is not a viable option; It doesn't take care of validations and replaces the view logic with lots of CSS. Not the best trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them readonly

```
<%= f.text_field :title, :readonly=> (can? :update, item)? true : false %>
```

Comment: It's just cosmetics; It depends whether you prefer writing lots of CSS (to style readonly controls as if they were plain text) or prefer some extra logic in the view.

And it doesn't address the issue of controller-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9) plugin for authorization .

Comment: As far as I could see, it's no different than declarative authorization or cancan: I still have to implement all the various logics in the controller/view.

Comment: Yes . I realized that you are already using a autorization framework. I guess there is no escaping the condition checks in the controllers .

Answer (score 0):

I dont belive theres any way to solve this with a plugin, the only option would be to change the controller code to:

```
@model=Model.new
@model.field = params[:model][:field] if can? ....
@model.save
```